# Magento2 Category Attribute

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I have created *Attribute* on category level [image]

now I want to fetch the value of this attribute. I have tried below code

```
 $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $object_manager =
 $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat_id);
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($object_manager->getData('google_taxonomy'));
```

but not result coming.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below solution,**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'); //Get Current Category
    $PCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($category->getId());
    
    echo $PCategory->getGoogleTaxonomy();
```